# Repeating Loop - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, repeat

basically I have run in to a bit of a problem which I can't seem to figure out. I am running a loop to check the database for specific values and display them in a table. It is all working fine the tables display fine apart from the fact there is a duplicated value?

The Main table called IR_Logs only contains 2 rows which is used as a joining table for the below code.

```
$SQL     = "SELECT ID, ItemID FROM IR_Logs";
$data    = $db->getResults($SQL);

$count   = mysql_num_rows($data);
echo '<p>Returned Results: '.$count.'</p>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
$ItemID     = $row[1];
$LocationID = $db->getValue("SELECT LocationID FROM IR_Logs WHERE ItemID = $ItemID");

$SQL          = "SELECT SiteManager, CompanyID, Reference FROM Customer_Sites WHERE Customer_Sites.ID = $LocationID";
$LocationData = $db->getResults($SQL);

while($row2= mysql_fetch_array($LocationData)){
    $SiteManagerID = $row2[0];
    $CompanyID     = $row2[1];
    $SiteReference     = $row2[2];

    $SQL         = "SELECT Name, Telephone, Email FROM Customer_Users WHERE CompanyID = $CompanyID AND ID = $SiteManagerID";
    $ManagerData = $db->getResults($SQL);

    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($ManagerData))
    {
        $Manager_Name      = $row3[0];
        $Manager_Telephone = $row3[1];
        $Manager_Email     = $row3[2];

        $SQL               = "SELECT (SELECT Reference FROM Inventory WHERE ID = ItemID), (SELECT Company FROM Customer_Accounts WHERE ID = CompanyID), (SELECT Reference FROM Customer_Sites WHERE ID = LocationID), Type, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d %M %Y'), CompanyID, LocationID FROM IR_Logs WHERE LocationID = $LocationID ORDER BY CompanyID ASC";
        $LogData           = $db->getResults($SQL);

        if(mysql_num_rows($LogData) <> 0){
            $HQEmail = $db->getValue("SELECT PrimaryEmail FROM Customer_Accounts WHERE ID = $CompanyID");
            $message .= '<h3>Site Ref: '.$SiteReference.'</h3>';
            $message .= '<p>For the Attention of '.$Manager_Name.', in regards to Site Reference: '.$SiteReference.'</p>';
            $message .= $blk->GetBlock(6);

            $message .= '<table style="border:1px solid black; padding: 10px;" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= '<tr>';
            $message .= '<td><strong>Reference</strong></td>';
            $message .= '<td><strong>Type</strong></td>';
            $message .= '<td><strong>Date</strong></td>';
            $message .= '</tr>';

            while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($LogData)){
                $Reference = $row4[0];
                $Location  = $row4[2];
                $Company   = $row4[1];
                $Type      = $row4[3];
                $Date      = $row4[4];
                $CompanyID = $row4[5];
                $LocationID= $row4[6];

                $message .= '<tr>';
                $message .= '<td>'.$Reference.'</td>';
                $message .= '<td>'.$Type.'</td>';
                $message .= '<td>'.$Date.'</td>';
                $message .= '</tr>';
            }
            $message .= '</table>';
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: what's the problem? Duplicated value where? (plz start using mysqli or PDO)

Comment: So you have a 'joining table'...  where is your `JOIN`?

Comment: We will to use **Distinct** keyword for avoiding duplicate values right? Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Using joins would make it easier to follow, and afraid you have not said which field is giving a duplicate.

For example the following is a quick hack (untested) at you code to eliminate some of the separate selects:-

```
<?php

$SQL     = "SELECT ID, ItemID FROM IR_Logs";
$data    = $db->getResults($SQL);

$count   = mysql_num_rows($data);
echo '<p>Returned Results: '.$count.'</p>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    $ItemID     = $row['ItemID'];
    $SQL          = "SELECT cs.SiteManager, cs.CompanyID, cs.Reference, cu.Name, cu.Telephone, cu.Email
                FROM IR_Logs ir 
                INNER JOIN Customer_Sites cs ON ir.LocationID = cs.ID
                INNER JOIN Customer_Users cu ON cs.CompanyID = cu.CompanyID AND cu.ID = cs.SiteManager";
    $LocationData = $db->getResults($SQL);

    while($row2= mysql_fetch_assoc($LocationData))
    {
        $SiteManagerID = $row2['SiteManager'];
        $CompanyID     = $row2['CompanyID'];
        $SiteReference     = $row2['Reference'];
        $Manager_Name      = $row3['Name'];
        $Manager_Telephone = $row3['Telephone'];
        $Manager_Email     = $row3['Email'];

        $SQL               = "SELECT i.Reference, ca.Company, cs.Reference, a.Type, DATE_FORMAT(a.Date, '%d %M %Y'), a.CompanyID, a.LocationID 
                                FROM IR_Logs a
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory i ON a.ItemID = i.ID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_Accounts ca ON a.CompanyID = ca.ID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_Sites cs ON a.LocationID = cs.ID
                                WHERE a.LocationID = $LocationID 
                                ORDER BY CompanyID ASC";
        $LogData           = $db->getResults($SQL);

        if(mysql_num_rows($LogData) <> 0){
            $HQEmail = $db->getValue("SELECT PrimaryEmail FROM Customer_Accounts WHERE ID = $CompanyID");
            $message .= '<h3>Site Ref: '.$SiteReference.'</h3>';
            $message .= '<p>For the Attention of '.$Manager_Name.', in regards to Site Reference: '.$SiteReference.'</p>';
            $message .= $blk->GetBlock(6);

            $message .= '<table style="border:1px solid black; padding: 10px;" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= '<tr>';
            $message .= '<td><strong>Reference</strong></td>';
            $message .= '<td><strong>Type</strong></td>';
            $message .= '<td><strong>Date</strong></td>';
            $message .= '</tr>';

            while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($LogData)){
                $Reference = $row4[0];
                $Location  = $row4[2];
                $Company   = $row4[1];
                $Type      = $row4[3];
                $Date      = $row4[4];
                $CompanyID = $row4[5];
                $LocationID= $row4[6];

                $message .= '<tr>';
                $message .= '<td>'.$Reference.'</td>';
                $message .= '<td>'.$Type.'</td>';
                $message .= '<td>'.$Date.'</td>';
                $message .= '</tr>';
            }
            $message .= '</table>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: My apologises of I did not provide enough information, I have looked at your code although I have not tested it, I have managed a quick fix. I still am quite new to PHP/MySQL and the following seems to of fixed it

`$SQL     = "SELECT DISTINCT LocationID, ItemID FROM IR_Logs GROUP BY LocationID";`

Comment: That is pretty much doing the job twice. The DISTINCT will only bring back 1 of each combination of LocationID, ItemID. The GROUP BY is used for aggregate functions (ie, if you wanted the MAX ItemID for a location), but using no aggregate function it will also eliminate any duplicate LocationID values (if there were 2 different ItemID values for a LocationID, then which one is returned would not be defined).